# Is There a method to find All the IP addresses connected to your network using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking

So basically i'm trying to create a program that gives all the Ip addresses connected to your device, then convert them to Mac address. The Mac adress converter part is working fine, but the Network Ip Scan is not working correctly... 
**Here's my code:**

```
import sys,os,socket
from getmac import get_mac_address

#GetNetworkIPs
addr_range = ("192.168.1.%d")
fname = ('NetUsersIP.txt')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.settimeout(2.0)

for i in range(1,20): 
    f = open(fname,'a')

    try:
        ip = (addr_range % i)
        socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
        print ("[+]",ip , "Exist in this Network.")
        f.write(ip+'\n')

    except socket.herror as ex:
        print ("[-]",ip, "Doesn't exist in this Network.")
        pass

f.close()

print("Getting IPs is Done!")
print("Converting IPs to Mac Addresses...")

#ToAddressMac
r = open(fname,'r')
for line in r:
    line = str(line)
    Addresses = get_mac_address(ip=line)
    print (Addresses)
```

**The output is:**

```
>
[+] 192.168.1.1 Exist in this Network.
[+] 192.168.1.2 Exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.3 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.4 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.5 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.6 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.7 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.8 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.9 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.10 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.11 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.12 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.13 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.14 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.15 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.16 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.17 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.18 Doesn't exist in this Network.
[-] 192.168.1.19 Doesn't exist in this Network.
Getting IPs is Done!
Converting IPs to Mac Addresses...
*Address mac of 192.168.1.1*
*Address mac of 192.168.1.2*
```

The output says that some of the generated Ip addresses aren't connected to the Network although they're connected.
**Is There any way to fix This?**

Comment: You have some problems about Python basics I think. This is not about your question.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL why? Is there anything wrong in the code because it’s working fine for me.

Comment: You are using `pass` for no reason. You are opening a file in a loop, which causes last ``_io.TextIOWrapper`` to garbage collected.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL yeah that’s true. But i didn’t get any error message and the IP addresses are written correctly in the file.

Comment: This is the problem, computers are not giving an error for every mistake. Python closes garbage collected files automatically but not closing is a bad habit.